# how to make this custom android tab layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to achieve this tab layout but i can't. I have already searched github but didn't find any help.
This is screenshot of the tabs
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Tablayout from support library. It has support for customViews. Checkout this link for reference https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`ViewPager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager) with a [`PagerTabStrip`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip).

Answer (score 0):

Have a vertical linear layout for the root layout.
Inside have a horizontal linear layout for the tabs, and another layout beneath it for each of the tab pages. When a tab is clicked, set the tab page's visibility to visible and all other tab pages to visibility gone

Comment: Don't do this. Android has library components. This is suggesting re-build those components from scratch.

Comment: Library components require the use of the support libraries